Is there anyway to change Solana dApp Store publish wallet?
I'm currently update my dApp using the json wallet:
> npx dapp-store validate -k <path_to_my_wallet.json> -b <path_to_android_build_tool>
> npx dapp-store create release -k <path_to_my_wallet.json> -b <path_to_android_build_tool> -u https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com
> npx dapp-store publish update -k <path_to_my_wallet.json> -u  https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com --requestor-is-authorized --complies-with-solana-dapp-store-policies

That json wallet is not 100% secure that even our team used Keybase to save it remotely and securely, but still lately someone got the file and steal all the wallet sol balance...
So now we want to move on with that wallet and use another wallet to publish the dApp, but we found no instruction about that, publish App using another wallet is failed in step npx dapp-store create release with this error:

┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── Error ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                                                                                                  │
│   The program [TokenMetadataProgram] at address [metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s] raised an error of code [7] that translates to     │
│   "Update Authority given does not match".                                                                                                       │
│                                                                                                                                                  │
│   Source: Program > TokenMetadataProgram [metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s]                                                           │
│                                                                                                                                                  │
│   Caused By: UpdateAuthorityIncorrect: Update Authority given does not match                                                                     │
│                                                                                                                                                  │
│   Program Logs:                                                                                                                                  │
│   | Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]                                                                               │
│   | Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success                                                                                  │
│   | Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]                                                                               │
│   | Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success                                                                                  │
│   | Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]                                                                               │
│   | Program log: IX: Create                                                                                                                      │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]                                                                                          │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success                                                                                             │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]                                                                                          │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success                                                                                             │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]                                                                               │
│   | Program log: Instruction: InitializeMint2                                                                                                    │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2828 of 230152 compute units                                                    │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success                                                                                  │
│   | Program log: Allocate space for the account                                                                                                  │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]                                                                                          │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success                                                                                             │
│   | Program log: Assign the account to the owning program                                                                                        │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]                                                                                          │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success                                                                                             │
│   | Program log: Transfer 2853600 lamports to the new account                                                                                    │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]                                                                                          │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success                                                                                             │
│   | Program log: Allocate space for the account                                                                                                  │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]                                                                                          │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success                                                                                             │
│   | Program log: Assign the account to the owning program                                                                                        │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]                                                                                          │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success                                                                                             │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]                                                                               │
│   | Program log: Instruction: SetAuthority                                                                                                       │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3090 of 172539 compute units                                                    │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success                                                                                  │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]                                                                               │
│   | Program log: Instruction: SetAuthority                                                                                                       │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3250 of 166069 compute units                                                    │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success                                                                                  │
│   | Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 94245 of 249700 compute units                                                   │
│   | Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s success                                                                                  │
│   | Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]                                                                               │
│   | Program log: IX: Mint                                                                                                                        │
│   | Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [2]                                                                              │
│   | Program log: Create                                                                                                                          │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]                                                                               │
│   | Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize                                                                                                 │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1622 of 101289 compute units                                                    │
│   | Program return: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA pQAAAAAAAAA=                                                                     │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success                                                                                  │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]                                                                                          │
│   | Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success                                                                                             │
│   | Program log: Initialize the associated token account                                                                                         │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]                                                                               │
│   | Program log: Instruction: InitializeImmutableOwner                                                                                           │
│   | Program log: Please upgrade to SPL Token 2022 for immutable owner support                                                                    │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1405 of 94649 compute units                                                     │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success                                                                                  │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]                                                                               │
│   | Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3                                                                                                 │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4241 of 90767 compute units                                                     │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success                                                                                  │
│   | Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 32443 of 118686 compute units                                                  │
│   | Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success                                                                                 │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]                                                                               │
│   | Program log: Instruction: MintTo                                                                                                             │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4538 of 78524 compute units                                                     │
│   | Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success                                                                                  │
│   | Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 82529 of 155455 compute units                                                   │
│   | Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s success                                                                                  │
│   | Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]                                                                               │
│   | Program log: IX: Verify                                                                                                                      │
│   | Program log: Update Authority given does not match                                                                                           │
│   | Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 17389 of 72926 compute units                                                    │
│   | Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x7                                                        │
│                                                                                                                                                  │
│                                                                                                                                                  │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
                                                                                                

So is there anyway to change
